# Dynamic parameter expansion

Tags: bash

Is dynamic `parameter expansion` possible in `Bash`?

```
$ TEST_1=12345
$ TEST_2=54321
$ for i in 1 2; do echo ${TEST_$i}; done
-bash: ${TEST_$i}: bad substitution
$ echo ${!TEST_*}
TEST_1 TEST_2
```

Desired output:

```
$ for i in 1 2; do echo ${TEST_$i}; done
12345
54321
```

Comment: Would an array or a hash better suit your needs?

Comment: Any time you find yourself using numbered variables, you should almost always be using an array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indirect parameter expansion (see man bash):

```
If the first character of parameter is an  exclamation  point  (!),  it
introduces a level of variable indirection.  Bash uses the value of the
variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable;
this  variable  is  then expanded and that value is used in the rest of
the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.   This  is
known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the expansions
of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below.  The exclamation  point
must  immediately  follow the left brace in order to introduce indirec-
tion.
```

That is:

```bash
for i in 1 2; do var="TEST_$i"; echo "${!var}"; done
```

**Test:**

```
$ TEST_1=12345
$ TEST_2=54321 
$ for i in 1 2; do var="TEST_$i"; echo "${!var}"; done
12345
54321
```